# How to remove gps updates after app was closed

Tags: android, gps

I have an app that uses `gps`. It is working fine unless the app is forced close (by the user or the android os) and reopen. Then I can't seem to close the `gps` updates.
This is my code:

```
private void registerLocationUpdates() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ParkOGuardActivity.class.getName()
            + ".LOCATION_READY");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    // minimum every 1 minutes, 5 kilometers 
    this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(this.provider, 5000,
            300000, pendingIntent);
}

private void cancelLocationUpdates() {
    if(pendingIntent != null){
        Log.d(TAG,pendingIntent!=null ? "pending is not null" : "pending is null");
        this.locationManager.removeUpdates(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

If i am calling the `cancelLocationUpdates()` method its ok, but after reopening the app (after it was forced close) the `pendingIntent` is null and i cant removeUpdates...
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether GPS is ON or OFF before starting the activity as below :

```
LocationManager lm;
boolean gpsOn = false;
if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )) {
    launchGPSOptions();
    if (!gpsOn) launchGPS();
}
```

Use the LaunchGPS and LaunchGPS Options in your code as below :

```
private void launchGPSOptions() {
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (!provider.contains("gps")) {
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        gpsOn = true;
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

private void launchGPS() {
    // final ComponentName toLaunch = new
    // ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.SecuritySettings");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(
            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    // intent.setComponent(toLaunch);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Comment: I think you named the methods wrongly - launchGPSOptions should be launchGPS and vice versa. To anyone reading the "launchGPSOptions", was a security hole patched in recent versions of android - you cant enable GPS programmatically - you can only launch the options and let the user enable it (the "launchGPS()" here)

Answer (score 2):

i found a solution. its an ugly one but it works:

```
private void cancelLocationUpdates() {
    if(pendingIntent == null) {
        registerLocationUpdates();
    }
    this.locationManager.removeUpdates(pendingIntent);
}
```

hope it helps.